# Dependency Hell on .NET (C#) Application Plugin

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, plugins, dependency-management

I am currently working on a plugin for a 3rd party WindowsForms application, where it will coexist amongst other plugins. Note that I have no control over the source or the files used by the base application (being it dll files, configuration files, etc.) nor over the other plugins that may be loaded at runtime.

Let us imagine that one of the other plugins, when loaded before mine, loads a dependency on version 1.0 of the library A (“A.dll”). If my plugin tries to load version 2.0 of the library A (also named “A.dll”), I am promptly greeted by the classic “System.IO.FileLoadException”.

After diving into the subject of dependency hell, I was presented with a few options (like [here](https://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2007/04/loading_multiple_versions_of_s.html) or [here](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/referencing-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-a-single-application) ). However all these options seem to focus on standalone applications, over which the developer has generally full control, that require two versions of the same library to be loaded (maybe for legacy support or any other strange reason). These solutions do not seem to be applicable on my case because of the plugin environment. Also, they often require:

- The insertion of an assembly in the GAC, which AFAIK will require administrative right on the final user’s machine, which I do not have;
- Control over the base application’s configuration file (*.exe.config), which I do not have.

Can anyone help me figure out a way to use a newer version of a library which is also used, as an older version, by another plugin, **keeping in mind the constraints I've described**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide library A.dll version 2.0 yourself, you could rename it to A.2.0.dll and reference that.

Comment: I have indeed control over the library A.dll, and that is my top options right now: simple and effective. However it requires me to rename the library for each version (for clarity purposes I simplified the problem: my library A.dll corresponds to a bunch of dll files). Before going with this option I would only like to know if there are other, maybe more elegant options to achieve this.

Comment: @PedroPinheiro Since all plugins are in the same directory and you cannot put anything in the GAC, I see no other option enabling you to use multiple versions of the same file.

Comment: We have a VS extension that relies on popular frameworks like Mono.Cecil, that can be likely loaded by other VS extensions. And we indeed experienced collisions in production for some users. Our option was to rename it Mono.Cecil.4NDepend.dll , NDepend being our product. Better suffix with 4YourProduct than suffix with a version 1) you rename third-parties once 2) who knows if there is no version collision

Comment: Thanks you all for your help. I successfully adopted this renaming strategy on my project and I can confirm it solves my initial issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the event AppDomain.AssemblyResolve to control which assembly is used depending on which assembly is trying to load it. Seems like a hack to me, but there probably is no clean way to solve this.

Comment: I agree with you, that seems like a hack. However, the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve should be handled by each plugin on the application, no? This may pose a problem, since I have no control over the other plugins on the application and I cannot impose them to use such method... That is why I am more incline to use a solution like the one proposed by MarTim, even if it is not an ideal solution either...

Comment: AFAIK the other assemblies live on the same appdomain as yours, so I think you'd be safe...You just have to make sure that if your plugin is requesting the assembly (or if your plugins version is requested)  the correct assembly is returned. If you ignore all other calls, then the default version of the assemlby will be retuned for the rest of the application.